# c++ find actual amount of elements in vector

Tags: c++, vector, size

```
std::vector<Card> m_vector;
m_vector.resize(10);
```

So I have something like that set up, I initialize the vector with a storage capacity of 10. However, when my program start I'll only have 2 elements to work with, and it'll increase later on at no fixed rate.

```
m_vector.size()
```

Will return 10, making it difficult for me to do a loop. Is there a way to find out the actual amount of elements inside the vector?

Answer (score 13):

The amount of elements after `resize(10)` **is** 10. You don't want to use `resize` if you only need two elements and a capacity of 10. Instead, you want:

```
std::vector<Card> m_vector(2);  // two elements
m_vector.reserve(10);           // space for 10 without reallocation
```

You can use `size()` to query the current number of elements, and `capacity()` for the maximal size you can have without reallocation.

Comment: Another question, since I declare the vector inside my header file, how would I initiate it inside my source file?

Comment: @user2963379: Show the code. Best to do that in a separate question (which will be closed as a duplicate of some other question explaining constructor initializer lists, I predict).

Comment: constructorDefn(int initialSize) : m_vector(initialSize) { m_vector.reserve(10); } or you can reserve first and do the resize after.  I'm not sure if the constructor is guaranteed to create a capacity equal to the initial size.  This is pretty simple.  Your best bet is to google or check out cplusplus.com to find some example code.

Answer (score 3):

*"vector with a storage capacity of 10"*

That's what `reserve` is for:

```
m_vector.reserve(10);
```

which will ensure that the internal storage of vector is big enough to hold 10 elements with no further reallocation needed.

`resize` on the other hand ensures that the vector contains 10 elements. It inserts empty elements if needed - which is also the reason why `size()` call returns `10`.